# Adding goroutine concurrency to make code efficient

Tags: go, goroutine

```
func sendCallback(status string, sender string, recipient string, gatewayMessageId string) *http.Response{
    // data massaging
    response, err := http.Post(postURL, "application/json", responseBody)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("POST : %s\n", status)
    return response
}

func callback(rdb *redis.Client) {
    for {
        data, err := rdb.RPop(ctx, "callback").Result()
        if err == redis.Nil {
            fmt.Println("Sleeping")
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second) // sleep for 2s
            continue
        }

        // more work

       sendCallback(status, sender, recipient, gatewayMessageId)
    }

}



func main() {
    rdb := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "127.0.0.1:6379",
        Password: "",
        DB:       0,
    })
    callback(rdb)
}
```

I understand that the above code is flawed as I'm waiting for "data" to be processed. However, I want it to be non-blocking, and as soon as data is present, I want it to be processed. I have been consuming tutorials on goroutines, but I'm unable to wrap my head around it.

**EDIT**

Based on @torek explanation, if I take the infinite loop out of the callback function, do it in the main function, and let the callback focus on its part, is this how goroutines should work?

```
func sendCallback(status string, sender string, recipient string, gatewayMessageId string) *http.Response{
    // data massaging
    response, err := http.Post(postURL, "application/json", responseBody)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("POST : %s\n", status)
    return response
}

func callback(data string) {

    parsedData := make(map[string]interface{})
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &parsedData)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    sender := parsedData["sender"].(string)
    recipient := parsedData["recipient"].(string)
    gatewayMessageId := parsedData["gateway_message_id"].(string)
  
    sendCallback("sent", sender, recipient, gatewayMessageId)
    sendCallback("delivered", sender, recipient, gatewayMessageId)
}

func main() {
    rdb := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "127.0.0.1:6379",
        Password: "",
        DB:       0,
    })
    for {
        data, err := rdb.RPop(ctx, "callback").Result()
        if err == redis.Nil {
            fmt.Println("Sleeping")
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second) // sleep for 2s
            continue
        }
        go callback(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Goroutines do not make code *efficient*. (They don't make it *in*-efficient either, although if not coded well, they generally *decrease* the efficiency slightly.) What they do is enable *concurrent, parallel work*. This may make the code easier to understand, and hence enable you, the programmer, to make it more efficient. This may enable you to use more CPUs on your host machine, making the program run faster in *real*-time but using more of the computer's resources. It may do nothing at all. It may make your code more complicated and harder for you to get right.

Comment: As a sort of general rule, if you can imagine your problem—whatever it is—being handled by a team of mostly-independent co-workers, each of whom picks up some *part* of the problem and works on it and passes the result along, you've found a way to decompose the work into goroutines: their input is their part of the problem, and their output is their result.

Comment: @torek, I made some changes based on your explanation of goroutines in the main function. Can you tell me if my approach makes more sense now?

Comment: I don't know anything about the Redis module you're using, so I can't speak to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a worker pool solution. The worker pool should help control CPU and memory usage. Big number of goroutines making CPU intensive operation are not optimal due to context switch overhead. But the most important benefit is having the http client under control. Your code creates a goroutine for each message received from redis. These goroutines then make a HTTP request. If the number of messages received from redis is higher than the number of HTTP requests that can be handled by the target service in a period of time, the target service will crash. Alternatively, the application may crash if it reaches a memory limit due to a large number of goroutines. You can set [`MaxConnsPerHost`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17:src/net/http/transport.go;l=206) which will prevent uncontrolled connection creation, but it will not prevent the creation of new goroutines. In my proposal, the application adapts the processing speed to the capabilities of the target service by leveraging the channel. You can increase the number of workers if you find that the target service can handle more requests and you have spare CPU power.

```
type message struct {
    Sender           string `json:"sender"`
    Recipient        string `json:"recipient"`
    GatewayMessageID string `json:"gateway_message_id"`
}

func sendCallback(status string, m message) *http.Response {
    // data massaging
    ...
    response, err := http.Post(postURL, "application/json", responseBody)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("POST : %s\n", status)
    return response
}

func worker(messages chan []byte) {
    for rawMessage := range  messages {
        m := message{}
        err := json.Unmarshal(rawMessage, &m)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        sendCallback("sent", m)
        sendCallback("delivered", m)
    }
}

const numberOfWorkers = 10

func main() {
    rdb := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "127.0.0.1:6379",
        Password: "",
        DB:       0,
    })
    messages := make(chan []byte, numberOfWorkers)
    for i := 0; i < numberOfWorkers; i++ {
        go worker(messages)
    }

    for {
        data, err := rdb.RPop(ctx, "callback").Result()
        if err == redis.Nil {
            fmt.Println("Sleeping")
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second) // sleep for 2s
            continue
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        messages <- []byte(data)
    }
}
```